# Игра "Загадки" на PHP

Tags: php

Друзья,у меня стоит веб-сервер OpenServer.Хочу на нём протестировать свой сайт.Сайт открывается.Загрузил туда игру "Загадки". Открываю игру "Загадки"(написанное на PHP),отвечаю на вопросы,вводя ответы в поля.Нажимаю "ответить"-никакой реакции.Ничего не происходит.Значения,вводимые мною в поля исчезают.Но в адресной строке ответы на вопросы у меня отображаются.Открываю через отладчик.При нажатии на "ответить" у меня в окне отладчика появляется файл main.js,который пустой.Как быть? Чё делать,ребята? Вот мой код:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный сайт студента Geekbrains</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

<?php 
include("menu.php");
?>

    <h1 align="center">Puzzle game</h1>

    <div class="box">

        <?php
        if(isset($_Get['useranswer1']) && isset($_Get['useranswer2']) && isset($_Get['useranswer3']))
{

$useranswer = $_Get['useranswer1'];
$score=0;
if($useranswer == "ёлка"){
    $score++;
}


$useranswer = $_Get['useranswer2'];
if($useranswer == "девушка"){
    $score++;
}


$useranswer = $_Get['useranswer3'];
if($useranswer == "море"){
    $score++;
}

echo "Вы угадали " . $score . " загадок";
}
        ?>

        <form method="Get">
        <p>Зимой и летом,одним цветом</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer1">
        <p>Среди навоза,одна роза</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer2">
        <p>Кругом вода,а с питьём беда</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer3"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ответить" >
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="index.php">Main</a>
        <a href="guess.html">Guessing game</a>
        <a href=#>Puzzle</a>
        <a href="generator sluchaynix chisel.html">Generator sluchaynix paroley</a>
        <p align="center">Copyright &copy;<?php echo date('Y')?> Shahin Karim</p>
    </div>
</body>


</html>`
```

Comment: Че там на гикбрейнсе, не сообщают что названия переменных в php чувствительны к регистру?

Comment: я новичок,поэтому пока не особо шарю.Стараюсь задания сам выполнять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказано переменные чувствительны к регистру, $_Get != $_GET.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Личный сайт студента Geekbrains</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

<?php
include("menu.php");
?>

<h1 align="center">Puzzle game</h1>

<div class="box">

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['useranswer1']) && isset($_GET['useranswer2']) && isset($_GET['useranswer3']))
    {

        $userAnswer = $_GET['useranswer1'];
        $score=0;
        if($userAnswer == "ёлка"){
            $score++;
        }


        $userAnswer = $_GET['useranswer2'];
        if($userAnswer == "девушка"){
            $score++;
        }


        $userAnswer = $_GET['useranswer3'];
        if($userAnswer == "море"){
            $score++;
        }

        echo "Вы угадали " . $score . " загадок";
    }
    ?>

    <form method="Get">
        <p>Зимой и летом,одним цветом</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer1">
        <p>Среди навоза,одна роза</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer2">
        <p>Кругом вода,а с питьём беда</p>
        <input type="text" name="useranswer3"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ответить" >
    </form>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <a href="index.php">Main</a>
    <a href="guess.html">Guessing game</a>
    <a href=#>Puzzle</a>
    <a href="generator sluchaynix chisel.html">Generator sluchaynix paroley</a>
    <p align="center">Copyright &copy;<?php echo date('Y')?> Shahin Karim</p>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: да,я понял.Решил этот вопрос.Получилось.Спасибо. Теперь возникла другая проблема.Надпись "Вы угадали столько-то загадок" не исчезает после обновления браузера.Ну,например,чтоб сыграть заново.Как сделать чтоб она исчезла ?